# How to use bulkCreate Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, typescript, sequelize.js, nest

I want to send my data, in an array, to my database with the bulkCreate function.
For that, I need to send the data, and the userId.

Example of data :

```
  {
    description: 'Pasta',
    creator: 'Andre',
    messageHelper: '',
    startDatetime: '2023-04-08T11:00:00',
    endDatetime: '2023-04-08T11:30:00',
    type: 'todo',
    groupId: 21
  },
  {
    description: 'Pasta',
    creator: 'Andre',
    messageHelper: '',
    startDatetime: '2023-04-15T11:00:00',
    endDatetime: '2023-04-15T11:30:00',
    type: 'todo',
    groupId: 21
  },
  {
    description: 'Pasta',
    creator: 'Andre',
    messageHelper: '',
    startDatetime: '2023-04-22T11:00:00',
    endDatetime: '2023-04-22T11:30:00',
    type: 'todo',
    groupId: 21
  },
```

requests.controller.ts :

```
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
    @Post('recurrent')
    async createRecurrent(@Body() request, @Request() req): Promise<RequestEntity[]> {
        return await this.requestService.createRecurrent(request, req.user.id);
    }
```

requests.service.ts (with the **bulkCreate**) :

```
    async createRecurrent(request: RequestDto[], userId): Promise<Request[]> {   
        return await this.requestRepository.bulkCreate<Request>({ ...request, userId });
    }

/*error on 'userId' : Argument of type '{ userId: any; length: number; toString(): string; toLocaleString(): string; pop(): RequestDto; push(...items: RequestDto[]): number; concat(...items: ConcatArray<RequestDto>[]): RequestDto[]; concat(...items: (RequestDto | ConcatArray<...>)[]): RequestDto[]; ... 25 more ...; [Symbol.unscopables](): { ...; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object[]'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userId' does not exist in type 'object[]'*/
```

requests.entity.ts :

```
@Table
export class Request extends Model<Request> {
    @AllowNull
    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
    })
    description: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    })
    creator: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    })
    messageHelper: string;

    @AllowNull
    @Column
    service: string

    @Column({
        type: DataType.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    })
    startDatetime: Date;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    })
    endDatetime: Date;
    @Column({
        type: DataType.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
    })
    isFree: number;
    
    @Column({
        type: DataType.ENUM,
        values: ['todo','meal'],
        allowNull: false,
    })
    type: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => Group)
    @Column
    groupId: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => Group)
    group: Group;
}
```

requestDto.ts :

```
enum RequestType {
    MEAL = 'meal',
    TODO = 'todo'
}

export class RequestDto {

    @IsOptional()
    readonly description: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    readonly creator: string;

    @IsOptional()
    readonly messageHelper: string;

    @IsOptional()
    readonly service: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    readonly startDatetime: Date;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    readonly endDatetime: Date;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEnum(RequestType, {
        message: 'type must be either meal or todo',
    })
    readonly type: RequestType;

    readonly isFree: number;

    readonly groupId: number;
}
```

userId is needed to join the table to an other one, so I can't get rid of it.

I think that because userId is not an array, it throw the error present in requests.service.ts.
I tried to change it to an array, but same error. I don't really understand the error, and searching on Internet didn't really help me.

Hope someone can help me there !
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace your service by this:

```js
request.forEach(d => d['userId'] = userId)
return await this.requestRepository.bulkCreate<Request>(request);
```

This will insert your `userId` into each object so that you'll be able to make the correct joints.